# How to convert date + time into timestamp ? - Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, parsing, timestamp

I am trying to sent data into database. I'm getting it from MQTT in JSON. I parsed it and tried to INSERT it into database. I think the problem is probably bad parsing.

In database i have type (timestamp, int)
Here is a code:

```
def on_message(client, userdataa, msg):
    print(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    json_data = json.loads(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    time = "";
    value = "";
    table = "";
    for k in json_data["readings"]:
        table = k["name"]
        a = k["value"].split(" ")
        time = a[1] + " " + a[2].replace('"','')
        value = a[0].replace('"','')
    to_database(time, value, table)

def to_database(time, value, table):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    print(cursor)
    try:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT into %s (date,%s) values(%s,%s)""",(table,table,time,int(value)))
        connection.commit()
        print("OK")
    except:
        connection.rollback()
```

So how can I parse time to timestamp ?

Comment: what is the value for `time`, just before the insert?  It should be something like `'2021-04-11 13:00'`, if shoud have the format 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM', and MySQL will convert that to timestamp.

Comment: A format is 2021-04-11 12:43:01 - almost same as you wrote but with milisec.

Comment: you mean seconds, not milliseconds... But what exact error message do you get ? Because the problem is not with the timestamp.

Comment: No error, just continue with except.. Maybe the execute commans is bad ?

Comment: Maybe you should add more (debugging) info to your `except:`, like: `print("Rollback because of error:", sys.exc_info()[0])`

Comment: you can't provide the table as an input in your `execute` call, that is the issue, identifiers can not be used with parameter substitution and you are doing just that

Comment: gold_cy have right, thank you !